# Sticky Footer with fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I have a problem regarding a sticky footer with a fixed header. I followed some of the solutions that seem to fit to what I wanted to achieve like (http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) or (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) and ([A true sticky footer with a fixed header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588959/a-true-sticky-footer-with-a-fixed-header)) but there are still somethings that I would like to solve.

Here is my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqvM6/5/)

Footer on the bottom of the page with tiny content or a lot of it  - Check!

No content underneath the header thanks to #siteContents:before (creates a spacer with the same height as the header) - Check!

Scroll bar still present with tiny content - Uncheck!

Footer in the bottom of the page when inside the div (siteContents) I have something like this - Uncheck!

```
(...)
<div id="siteContents" class="clearfix">
     <div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://www.datavocabulary.org/Something/">.. </div>
</div>
(...)
```

Can the **itemscope div** be the responsible for this behavior?

It seems to be because when the page is loading and the height to place the footer is calculated by the browser it places the footer on the bottom of what he knows. The content inside the itemscope div (forms, tables,..) overflows over the missplaced footer.

What can I do to keep the sticky footer at the bottom in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `min-height` and `position: absolute;` for that kind of layout. So your container will be displayed with at least 100% height:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Your sticky footer will need `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` so that the element always stays at the bottom of its parent element (`.wrapper`):

```
.page-foot {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;  
}
```

Your header will be the same, but with `position: fixed;`. Since you don't want your header and footer to overlap your content you need to set both `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`. You could use javascript to set `padding-top`/`padding-bottom`, if you don't want to use a fixed `padding`. As far as I know there is no CSS-only way to achieve the same effect.

Here's a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UAkd5/1/).

Comment: Before you edited your answer I tried with the display: table (parent div) and display: table-cell (child) and it actually worked. Thanks.

Comment: @MrQ You're right, it worked, but i used `display:table` and `display: table:cell;` only because i thought you don't need to set a fixed `height`/`padding`. But actually you still had to. The edited answer does exactly the same but with less markup and less CSS.