# How can I lock both the top and bottom of a Google sidebar?

Tags: css, google-apps-script

Following the directions in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/css#sidebars) I was able to add a locked footer to my sidebar.   How can I also create header area that is locked also.

**Update:** Sometimes it is a matter of finding the correct search terms.  I have since found the answer in another post: [A true sticky footer with a fixed header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588959/a-true-sticky-footer-with-a-fixed-header)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Thank you, I wound up finding my answer once I got the correct search terms, and updated the post with a link.

Comment: You want to create a fixed header?

Comment: A fixed header and footer, with the scrollbar only showing up in the middle, when the content gets too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got a fixed header and footer, with a dynamic content middle, and a scroll-bar that only shows for the dynamic content, using css.

html

```
<div id="header">
    <button onClick="addLine()">Add</button>
</div>
<div id="content">Add Lines
    <ul id="add"></ul>
</div>
<div id="footer">Something</div>
```

javascript (with jQuery 2.1.3)

```
function addLine() {
    $("#add").append("<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>-</li>");
}
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#header, #footer {
    position: fixed;
    background:gray;
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    top:0px;
    height:100px;
}
#footer {
    bottom:0px;
    height:100px;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    bottom:100px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/edlisten/tq60e0u1/